# Beginner Java problem: ____ cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, function

I'm currently learning Java from [this tutorial](https://www.learnjavaonline.org/en/Functions), and while the nomenclature sometimes confuses me (heavily with this chapter, actually), I'm good enough at figuring out why the code works. Except in this case, it doesn't, and it's not my code not working, it's the tutorial's.

This is the snippet giving me problems:

```
public class Chapter6 {

    public void bar2(Student s1, Student s2) {
        Student joe = new Student("joe");
        Student jack = new Student("jack");
        bar2(joe, jack);

    }

}
```

Eclipse complains that for line 3, Student cannot be resolved to a type (twice). I can fix this by creating a class called Student, but then it still complains for lines 4 and 5 that the constructor Student(string) is undefined. As my final attempt at solving it, I put this code in the Student class file (and changed the class in the first line from Chapter6 to Student), but that didn't solve anything.

I'm happy for any help, and happier still if you could ELI5, because as I said, the nomenclature of functions really confuses me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create a class Student, the errors that you are getting are because when the program compiles, tries to find the Student class. And it's not imported.

```
 public class Student {

   private String name;

   // This is the constructor, it will get called when you do: new Student("joe")
   public Student(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}
```

Then in the class chapter6.

```
public class Chapter6 {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Student joe = new Student("joe");
        Student jack = new Student("jack");
        bar2(joe, jack);
    }

    public void bar2(Student s1, Student s2) {
        // Do stuff here
    }

}
```

Be aware that if you leave the method call bar2 in the method bar2 how it is now, you will get an error StackOverFlow, because the method is calling itself indefinitely

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class `Student` with a constructor with a String parameter.

Then, don't forget to import it in the `Chapter6` class

Answer (score 0):

@[Ezequiel Falcon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60532305/8127620) answer is right.
You need to create a `Student` Class first then import `Student` class in `Chapter6`. Also, you need to modify your `bar2` method in `Chapter6` Class.

```
public class Student {

 private String name;

 public Student (String name) {

  this.name = name;

 }

}
```